# Google App Engine - Python and render from bigtable

Tags: python, google-app-engine, templates

I there:

I am experimenting with GAE and i wish to create a CMS using plain python (not Django or another framework).  And my problem is that GAE does not allow to save files, so i can save a user-created template in a folder.

When you want to render a file, you use the next command:

```
    tmpl = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates/mypage.html')
    self.response.out.write(render(tmpl, context))
```

Is there are a way to render directly from a registry from BigTable or from a variable instead of a file? (without using Django).

Comment: The App Engine datastore is built on BigTable, but it's not BigTable - it's the datastore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a start, if you're using `template.render`, you *are* using a framework: the minimal "webapp" framework included with GAE. And, of course, the `template` module itself is a thin wrapper around Django's template library. However, the wrapper - which takes care of a few incompatibilities between Django and webapp - doesn't expose a method for rendering directly from a string.

It *does* allow access to the basic django `Template` class, which can be used to instantiate a template directly from a template string:

```
tmpl = template.Template(template_string)
tmpl.render(template.Context(context))
```

This might work - or it might not, because of those incompatibilities.

Comment: thanks. However, i am unable to figure how to {"% include %}" inside the template.

Comment: Well, that's one of the things that probably won't ever work in this context.

Comment: You can write custom template loaders for Django, which are called to resolve filenames in includes etc. This is a much more advanced topic, though, and you should definitely start by reading up and learning how the templating system works. You're trying to do something very difficult, with only a basic knowledge of what's going on.